# Disabling keypress event listener when a condition is met

Tags: javascript

I have a key press event listener on all direction keyboard keys which is setup when the page loads. I want to disable this event listener when the user reaches the finish line on my maze game. I have attempted to do this (see code below) but when the user reaches the finish line, the event listener remains active and the user can continue to move around the maze.

I would like to do this just using vanilla javascript. Any suggestions you have would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the event listener:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", moveCharacter = (e) => {
                    let currentPos = naviCtrl.currentPosition(DOMstrings.boxes, DOMstrings);
                    document.querySelector(DOMstrings.timer).innerHTML = "";

                    const key_code = e.which || e.keyCode;
                    switch (key_code) {
                        case 37: //left arrow key
                            naviCtrl.moveLeft(currentPos, chosenCharacter);
                            playerCtrl.playerFinished();
                            break;
                        case 38: //Up arrow key
                            naviCtrl.moveUp(currentPos, chosenCharacter);
                            playerCtrl.playerFinished();
                            break;
                        case 39: //right arrow key
                            // naviCtrl.removeCharacter(DOMstrings);
                            naviCtrl.moveRight(currentPos, chosenCharacter);
                            playerCtrl.playerFinished();
                            break;
                        case 40: //down arrow key
                            naviCtrl.moveDown(currentPos, chosenCharacter);
                            playerCtrl.playerFinished();
                            break;
                    }
                });
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
playerFinished: (currentPos) => {
            if (document.querySelector(DOMstrings.characterImg).parentNode.id === 36 || document.querySelector(DOMstrings.characterImg).parentNode.id === "box-36") {

                //1. stop player movement 
                document.removeEventListener("keydown", appController.moveCharacter);

            }
        },
```

Comment: Have you tried `document.removeEventListener("keydown", moveCharacter);` since you defined `moveCharacter` and not `navigationController.moveCharacter`?

Comment: Thank you! what a silly error. For some reason I thought I had created a method rather than a function. Thanks for your help

Comment: Add it as an answer and I will vote for it

Comment: Thanks John. Don't forget to mark it as "the" answer as well by clicking the checkmark at the top-left of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `document.removeEventListener("keydown", moveCharacter);` since you defined `moveCharacter` and not `navigationController.moveCharacter`.